# Realtime database not getting updated in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image]A Very basic program on firebase realtime database in Android Studio, trying to update the name, it is not reflecting in the realtime database. However I could not find any error while running it or in the logs. Please help.

Image of dependencies from gradle:

[image: image of dependencies from gradle]

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    text = findViewById(R.id.editTextName)
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn)

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")

    btn.setOnClickListener {

       val username: String = text.text.toString()
      Log.e("clicked",username)
       database.child("userName").setValue(username)

   }
}
```

Comment: If none of your interactions with the Realtime Database work, consider passing the database URL to the `getInstance()` call: `database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("database URL here").getReference("Users")`.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `.setValue(username)` operation to see if something goes wrong? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo
I have updated my question with the screenshots, I am still facing issue which I am not able to figure out exactly why the real time database it not getting updated

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have tried that as well, and attached screenshot , still it is not working

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener as mentioned in my latest comment?